# Looping with 001 to 022 instead of 1 to 22

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a few files which have a numbering system likes this:

```
chr001_genetic_file.txt 
chr002_genetic_file.txt 
...
chr022_genetic_file.txt
```

As well as another set like this:

```
genetic_files.001.european.txt
...
genetic_files.022.european.txt
```

I am trying to run a for loop: `for(i in 001 to 022)` but R keeps throwing a naming error saying the file `genetic_files.1.european.txt doesn't exist`.

I could rename all my files which seems like a headache in order to get "i in 1 to 22" to work. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Have you tried using something like `sprintf("%03d", i)`?

Comment: Thanks Ronak, I'm not trying to add 0s, I'm trying to incorporate them into a loop which seems to want to use 1-22. I don't think this is the same

Comment: @duckmayr is that in place of the beginning of the for loop or is that a transformation step prior to using the files?

Comment: If you show your code (loop) we might be able to help better/faster.

Comment: @duckmayr's approach is correct.  Use numeric `1:22` to define your loop, and (eg) `paste0("chr", sprintf("%03d", i), "_genetic_file.txt")` to obtain your file names.  By the way, one of the `apply` family of functions is both more compact and efficient than a `for` loop, though the differences will be negligible in a simple case like this.

Comment: tacrolimus, The latter; @Limey  has got the idea I was putting out there

Comment: Try `for(i in sprintf("%03d", 1:22)) { foo(paste0("chr", i, "_genetic_file.txt")) }`

Comment: Also, consider using `list.files()`, instead of patching filenames with paste which might not even exist.